# having trouble understanding bytes being manipulated

Tags: python, encoding

I use pyDes to create a token to add to my request's headers (I use `requests` library).

`{'token': pyDes.triple_des(auth_secret_key).encrypt(auth_message, padmode=2)}`

output of `token's` value is `b')\x8d\xa85\xe0;F\x81\xaeL3d\x86\x9eF\xf7'`. I add this key/value pair to my requests headers. but on the server side when I check the request's headers this value is changed to `b')\xc2\x8d\xc2\xa85\xc3\xa0;F\xc2\x81\xc2\xaeL3d\xc2\x86\xc2\x9eF\xc3\xb7'`. I notice that there are `xc2` between the bytes seprated with `\`. what is the reason?

Comment: Handling raw binary data on the Internet is often an issue. Try encoding the data into the base64 format before sending, then decoding it upon receiving.

Comment: @AlexHall sure, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encoding token into base64 solved the issue.

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(bytes(token, encoding='utf-8'))
```